# c++ 17 incomplete type works in map but not unordered_map. Are both undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c++17, unordered-map, incomplete-type

It seems like I can use an incomplete type for map but not unordered_map. Are they both actually undefined behavior in c++ 17? For example:

```
// this compiles
class Foo {
public:
  map<string, Foo> mymap;
};

// this does not compile
class Foo {
public:
  unordered_map<string, Foo> mymap;
};
```

It also appears like vector compiles as well.

```
// this also compiles
class Foo {
public:
  vector<Foo> myvec;
};
```

I guess my question is can I use vector and map for incomplete types?

Comment: Ah, it looks like it does. Apologies. Actually it looks like the answer is from 2012, I'm not sure if this has changed. It looks like perhaps vector has been relaxed in this regard.

Comment: As I remember, only `std::vector`, `std::list` and `std::forward_list` containers allows incomplete type, from standard.